# SVN: Why does command 'svnadmin load' work without pre-revprop-change hook but 'svnrdump load' requires it?

Tags: svn

When loading SVN dump files using `svnadmin load` and `svnrdump load`, only `svnrdump load` requires using the *pre-revprop-change* hook even though both of these methods are changing the revision properties.

Why is it that `svnrdump load` requires this commit hook while `svnadmin load` does not?

For the following examples, this is the dump command used:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/source/repo > dumpfile.svn_dump
```

This will work without pre-commit hook:

```
svnadmin load /path/to/dest/repo < dumpfile.svn_dump
```

This will **not** work unless there is a pre-commit hook:

```
svnrdump load file://path/to/dest/repo < dumpfile.svn_dump
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but these tests were all done on Windows 10 using SVN 1.8.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svnrdump` is a command that runs on the URL and may or may not have direct access to the repository.

> To operate properly `svnrdump load` requires that the target
> repository have revision property modification enabled via the
> `pre-revprop-change` hook

Whereas `svnadmin` is an administrative tool that never runs on the URL and always needs direct repository access.

> svnadmin is the administrative tool for monitoring and repairing your
> Subversion repository. svnadmin works via direct repository access
> (and thus can only be used on the machine that holds the repository),
> it refers to the repository with a path, not a URL

So all command from `svnadmin` will never executes hooks as it operates directly on the repository.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, that makes a lot of sense!